# how to recover Deleted contacts in android 10 programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, contacts, android-contacts

I want to create an app which can recover deleted contact. Its work in all other devices but in android 10 the application cant get the deleted contact. Is there any solution to get the deleted contact from the android 10.

Here is my code which can recover the deleted contacts

```
public static final String WHERE_MODIFIED1 = "( " + ContactsContract.RawContacts.DELETED + "=1)";
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query((ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI),
            null, WHERE_MODIFIED1, null, (DeletedContactRecovery.hasHoneycomb() ? "sort_key" : "display_name") + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

    assert cur != null;
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phone = null;
            //if (!(Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)) {
            System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

            // get the phone number
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);
            assert pCur != null;
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                phone = pCur.getString(
                        pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                System.out.println("phone" + phone);
            }
            pCur.close();
            //}
            if (id != null) {
                contactList.add(new Contact(name, phone, id));
            }
            Log.e("hvy", "onCreaterrView  Phone Number: name = " + name
                    + " No = " + phone);
        }
    }
    cur.close();
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this ? If yes, can you please share the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't do this action because you have not any access to contact application special space.
every app have a special space that other application haven't any access to it.

may be by root `user` you can recover contact.

go to `Developer Options` and enable `Unlock OME`  then you need a application for control root request like kingo root

Comment: but its working in the lower api level in android 8 its working properly without root

Comment: so may be changed ```ContactsContract.RawContacts.DELETED```  see doc

Answer (score 0):

For an android app either to block or recover contacts it is necessary to make it default Dailer or SMS app. I had once the same issue when i tired to read block contacts in android 10 even my app was working perfectly below android 10. I don't know exactly what is the solution for you here but try to make the app default and then try to read contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover your deleted contacts using this app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.recovermycontacts

Comment: I am a developer and i wants to build my app. I know that different apps are available in play store. Thanks for your contribution